# Send content of a csv file to a matrix

Tags: c

I'm having trouble sending the content of a csv file to a matrix (the idea is to send a table that's in the csv file to a matrix to be easier to handle the rows and columns). I only managed until now to read the content of the csv and print. Thanks for your attention.

Here you have the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
    char file[100];

    printf("Para escolher o ficheiro escreva o diretorio do ficheiro: \t");
    gets(file);
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");

    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            printf("%c", fgetc(fp));
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
        printf("Erro na abertura do ficheiro!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post a portion of the input `.csv` file in a separate code block here. Note that the number of data columns is relevant and we don't know how many. Also, are some of the columns text strings, etc.? So, we need to be able to see the format of the input data. Other things to note: Are the columns abutting (e.g.) `1,2,3` [the usual] or can they have whitespace (e.g.) `1, 2, 3`?

Comment: The word “send” indicates that you are pushing data to some device or program external to your own program. The words “read” and “load” describe _obtaining_ data from some external source to fill a data structure. The same word correlations exist in Spanish and, I presume, Portuguese. Likewise, you ask the user to enter a _directory_ name, but then use that input for the _file name_. (I should also say _don’t use gets()_.)

Comment: It might be worth spending some time with https://www.google.com/search?q=read+csv+c

Comment: Don't use `feof`. Just stop when `fgetc` returns `EOF` (e.g.) `while (1) { int chr = fgetc(fp); if (chr == EOF) break; printf("%c", chr); }` But, for `.csv` input you probably want `fgets` to get an entire _line_ at once.

Comment: regarding: `gets(file);`  The `gets()` function has been depreciated for years and completely eliminated from the C language around 2009.  Strongly suggest using `fgets()` (which has a different parameter list, so read the manual)

Comment: @CraigEstey `code` 
2;51.5;144.0;24.80 (paragraph)
5;62.3;157.0;25.30 (paragraph)
10;52.8;141.0;26.60 (paragraph) 
10;34.5;120.0;24.00 (paragraph)
1;41.6;131.0;24.20 (paragraph)
5;49.0;144.0;23.80 (paragraph)
6;47.1;142.0;23.50 (paragraph)
2;51.8;144.5;24.80 (paragraph)
1;55.6;135.0;30.50 (paragraph)
9;51.9;150.0;23.10 (paragraph)
9;48.5;139.0;25.10 (paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, you probably want to read a line at a time.

Given the data in your comment (which should be in a code block), you can use `fscanf` to read it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     do { } while (0)
#endif

// a single row of data
typedef struct {
    int idx;
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
} data_t;

size_t count;
data_t *data;

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc < 1)
        exit(1);

    // open the .csv file
    FILE *xf = fopen(argv[0],"r");
    if (xf == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    data_t *cur;

    while (1) {
        // increase the array count
        ++count;

        // add more space
        data = realloc(data,sizeof(*data) * count);
        if (data == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(1);
        }

        // read in a row of the .csv data
        cur = &data[count - 1];
        if (fscanf(xf,"%d;%lf;%lf;%lf",&cur->idx,&cur->a,&cur->b,&cur->c) != 4)
            break;

        dbgprt("DEBUG: idx=%d a=%f b=%f c=%f\n",cur->idx,cur->a,cur->b,cur->c);
    }

    fclose(xf);

    // we preallocated an extra element, so trim the array to the actual count
    --count;
    data = realloc(data,sizeof(*data) * count);

    // print the array
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
        cur = &data[idx];
        printf("idx=%d a=%f b=%f c=%f\n",cur->idx,cur->a,cur->b,cur->c);
    }

    // free the array
    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

---

I assume from your top comment that each space is a separate line in the `.csv` file:

```
2;51.5;144.0;24.80
5;62.3;157.0;25.30
10;52.8;141.0;26.60
10;34.5;120.0;24.00
1;41.6;131.0;24.20
5;49.0;144.0;23.80
6;47.1;142.0;23.50
2;51.8;144.5;24.80
1;55.6;135.0;30.50
9;51.9;150.0;23.10
9;48.5;139.0;25.10
```

---

Here is the output of the program:

```
idx=2 a=51.500000 b=144.000000 c=24.800000
idx=5 a=62.300000 b=157.000000 c=25.300000
idx=10 a=52.800000 b=141.000000 c=26.600000
idx=10 a=34.500000 b=120.000000 c=24.000000
idx=1 a=41.600000 b=131.000000 c=24.200000
idx=5 a=49.000000 b=144.000000 c=23.800000
idx=6 a=47.100000 b=142.000000 c=23.500000
idx=2 a=51.800000 b=144.500000 c=24.800000
idx=1 a=55.600000 b=135.000000 c=30.500000
idx=9 a=51.900000 b=150.000000 c=23.100000
idx=9 a=48.500000 b=139.000000 c=25.100000
```

Comment: I don´t know but that code doesnt work in my pc...

Comment: Did you check the exit code (e.g. `echo $?`). If it's non-zero, did you invoke the program correctly? (e.g.) `./myprogram mydata.csv`? where `mydata.csv` is the file that has the data (use the data that I posted). I didn't put an error message in the program in the first `if`, so if you invoke the program with no arguments, it will exit [silently] with exit code 1.